gigalixir page not found
I'm trying to create a database via clia, but running into "Page not found". I then created a db in the web ui, but I'm still unable to get going via cli. Any pointers?
$ gigalixir pg:create --free
A word of caution: Free tier databases are not suitable for production and migrating from a free db to a standard db is not trivial. Do you wish to continue? [y/N]: y
Page not found

$ gigalixir pg
Page not found

$ gigalixir config
Page not found



Sounds like a transient error on their side. Do you still experience the issue now? Did you reach out to their support?

no, trying to deploy on hetzner now :D
